# ssh on Ubuntu fails after first time : Asymmetric routes, SSH connection fails to properly establish

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, routing, connection

I have been baffled by this problem... I have an exs host on subnet 10.128.0.1 and guests on 10.128.20.1 subnet. I have another box on 10.128.0.1 subnet with vms on 10.129.18.1 ...

Router is simple multihomed to encompass all three subnets with main lan of 10.128.0.1 and multihomed for 10.128.18.1 and 10.128.20.1 ...

I can `ssh` to any guest on 10.128.18.1 guests, but for 10.128.20.1 guests, I can `ssh` only once, then have to restart the guest ? I see that packets reaching the guest VM with `tracedump` ... but for some reason connection just times out or it is sitting there waiting for something. I did turn off `useDNS` in `sshd_config` since local dns server still not configured ... thinking it was affecting it.

Somehow I think it is my `sshd` configuration issue but cannot hone on it...

Here is my `sshd_config`:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
AllowUsers testuser
UseDNS no
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```

Would appreciate some insights.

Comment: what does ssh -v show?

Comment: Hi Eddie, it hangs after this ... "debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2"

Comment: I can ping the server (s) on that subnet - so routing issues are ruled out..

Comment: The more I think, it could esx host configuration issue since it is affecting all the VMs the same way ... Is it possible that dns settings of esx host is coming into play ? Theoretically they shouldn't ...

Comment: Hmm, what does your ssh_config look like? You could try Protocol 2,1 to see if that makes a difference but you need to figure out a way to use 2 if you can.

Comment: @EddieDunn System administrators were phasing out SSH version 1 a decade ago. The probability of a problem being caused by the use protocol version 2 and somehow being "solved" by using version 1 is negligible. However there is a minor performance improvement in recent versions of the OpenSSH client, which is enabled when the client is configured for version 2 only, that optimization will be disabled if version 1 is enabled. It is not entirely impossible that this optimization can influence behavior in some weird corner cases.

Comment: Eddie , Kasper is correct, protocol 1 will not and did not help ... This could esx configuration issue as it is affecting all the VMs ... but sure is really weird issue

Comment: Try connecting to port 22 using telnet. I am suspecting the server is never sending a banner.

Comment: What do the server logs say?

Comment: @kasperd I am aware of that (which I why I also said that it was not secure) and was not suggesting it as a solution. Just a troubleshooting step.

Comment: Can you configure the server to syslog to a box you can access? You might be able to see what is happening on that side.

Comment: The first ssh succeeds, right? You get access to the machine? If so, could you maybe run tcpdump (to a file) on both server and client for your second attempt? If the first ssh does not succeed in giving you a shell, it could be something system-related that is making the machine hang. Do you have access to the console through VMWare?

Comment: Hi Law29, I have full access to the machine, will get the dump after both attempts on both ends of tunnel. One thing is that I am tunneling via openVPN but that should be fine as the VPN client subnets are working fine.

Comment: @kasperd ... Tried telnet on port 22 - it seems to connect but don't get control ...

Comment: @JennyD - will put out all the logs, not near the machine right now ... have bounced esxi host remotely, seems it is not coming - will have to go to datacenter to reboot.

Comment: Solved !!! There was asymmetric path from the subnet in question. Though interestingly when we connect first, the path was ok and consistently for second connection ack frames were getting routed via different path... Whew!!! That was a toughie - thanks all for your help, everything helped to narrow down. Next time I am hiring a certified network administrator to setup up complex network.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question as the problem was solved. This is for the benefit of others who have similar issues.

Issue turned out to be Asymmetrical route that was created. For TCP, the session involves sending SYN, ACKS and other frames to establish connection. If there is asymmetric route, it still is OK from TCP level, however if the router has firewall that has SPI enabled, and sees ack coming over different route, it is going to terminate that packet i.e. it is doing its job. Ideally you want to avoid asymmetric routes, but in practical world not possible for e.g. you have two routers or software gateway (VPN gateway for eg) on same subnet or your static route is not configured correctly, this will happen.

If router supports, enable asymmetrical routing and this problem will go away. Also try disabling SPI (not recommended though) on your router. Do this if you are well protected by your NAT.

For my case I have turned on asymmetrical routing in my firewall. Eventually I am going trouble shoot the overlapping routes if any...

One cliche statement though, asymmetrical routes are pain in the rear to debug as you are totally clueless initially till you start tedious process of elimination, especially if you setting new setup like I was.